# SQL - Is it possible to select all Distinct Values from one column where all values from another column match?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dataset, distinct

I have researched previous questions, but couldn't find one that replicated mine or that was easy to understand. I'm hoping this is a relatively simple one to answer anyway, if i have duplicated, sorry.

I have a table in SQL that catalogs all our reports (as per simplified version below).
It has `ReportCountryID` as Primary Key, `ReportID`, `CountryID`, `CountryName`.

```
ReportCountryID  ReportID    CountryID   CountryName
0001                 8447           12   Bosnia
0002                 9740           13   Bosnia & Herzegovina
0003                 9278           13   Bosnia & Herzegovina
0004                 8447          128   Czech Rep
0005                 9740           25   Czech Republic
0006                 9278           25   Czech Republic
0007                 9714           83   Russia
0008                 9742           83   Russia
0009                 9672           83   Russia
0010                 9740           83   Russia
0011                 9278           83   Russia
0012                 8447           83   Russia
0013                 9740          106   UK
0014                 9278          106   UK
0015                 9252          124   UK & NI
0016                 9740          110   USA
0017                 8447          108   United States
0018                 9252          110   USA
0019                 9278          110   USA
```

What I am trying to do is find out which Reports use all the same Country Names and what are those country names?

In the example above, only Reports 9278 and 9740 use Bosnia & Herzegovina, Czech Republic, Russia, UK and USA. However, this is only a small sample I picked from being able to visually see differences.

Could output look like?:-

```
9728                  9740
Bosnia & Herzegovina  Bosnia & Herzegovina
Czech Republic        Czech Republic
Russia                Russia
UK                    UK
USA                   USA
```

Comment: What would the desired output look like?   Can you post sample output instead of trying to describe it with words?

Answer (score 0):

The following select will return all records that have the same `CountryName` atleast once more in the table and then grouping them to ignore the `ReportCountryID` field:

```
select ReportID,
       CountryID,
       CountryName
  from ReportCountryTable rpt1
 where exists (select 1
                 from ReportCountryTable rpt2
                where rpt2.ReportCountryID <> rpt1.ReportCountryID
                  and rpt2.CountryName     = rpt1.CountryName) -- or you can use rpt2.CountryID = rpt1.CountryID
 group by ReportID,
          CountryID,
          CountryName
 order by CountryID,
          CountryName
```

The output, with your data subset, would look as follow:

```
ReportID    CountryID   CountryName
----------- ----------- -----------------------------------------------------------
9278        13          Bosnia & Herzegovina
9740        13          Bosnia & Herzegovina
9278        25          Czech Republic
9740        25          Czech Republic
8447        83          Russia
9278        83          Russia
9672        83          Russia
9714        83          Russia
9740        83          Russia
9742        83          Russia
9278        106         UK
9740        106         UK
9252        110         USA
9278        110         USA
9740        110         USA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tempTable table
(
  countryID int
)

--Match with five countries as per the example
INSERT INTO @tempTable values 
( 25 ), (13) ,(110) , (106), (83)
--In case you want to match all distinct countries then you can comment above line and use below line.
--INSERT INTO @tempTable 
--SELECT distinct CountryID from Table1

SELECT T1.ReportID FROM
Table1 T1
JOIN ( SELECT countryId from @tempTable ) T2
ON T1.CountryID = T2.countryID
GROUP BY T1.ReportID
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT  T1.CountryID) = ( SELECT COUNT(countryID) FROM @tempTable)
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh      Thanks for your answer. However, when I try this on the example data, only ReportID 9278 is returned.

Comment: @jellybean1977, i tried with sample data and getting both 9278 and 9740, here is sql fiddle demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa0a3a/1

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. Your code is working now. I think I must have made a mistake when creating my example table. However, if I use the bit where you say if I want to match all distinct countries, I get no result?

Comment: @jellybean1977, yes there are no reports that have all countries associated, you can accept the answer as it is working for you

Comment: sorry, it works when you already know which countries should match. What I'm really after is a way of finding out which reportIDs match the same countries in a much bigger data set. Is that even possible?

Comment: @jellybean1977, in case you don't know defined country set, the question would be different, and answer would be multiple combinations, input would be 5 to mean matching five countries and the output would be any set of 5 matching countries or output should list all such combination for each number, better to do in application layer if we want to all such combinations